Convert text file to audio file
Is there a command line tool, that allows converting a input text file directly into a audio file (e.g. mp3).
The tool should support as language English and German, and should not sound like a robot.
I tired already espeak(ng), festival and say. They sound only like a robot (and are not working in german)
Is there a free tool on Ubuntu that allows completing this task?

This question is similar to: How to text-to-speech output using command-line?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

What do you mean by "converting"? Do you want to encode the binary contents of the file as audio or do you want the sound of a human voice reading the file? Or maybe some other way to encode?

@terdon -> I want to convert the text files in to an audio file such as mp3. That I can listen to it from that file via a normal audio player.
